# Creating polyline from .txt files, CreateObject cannot create geometry from inputs

Tags: arcpy

After trying to fix the issue with the advice from my previous post, I'm nowhere. Any insights?

```
 Python 2.7.14 (v2.7.14:84471935ed, Sep 16 2017, 20:19:30) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
    Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
    >>> 
     RESTART: \\SNHU-LABS-UTIL2.snhu-labs.com\userprofiles$\karen.obando\Documents\GP_VDI\Final\Final.py 
    \\SNHU-LABS-UTIL2.snhu-labs.com\userprofiles$\karen.obando\Documents\GP_VDI\Final\Data
    START
    7_10_2014.txt
    \\SNHU-LABS-UTIL2.snhu-labs.com\userprofiles$\karen.obando\Documents\GP_VDI\Final\Data\7_10_2014.txt
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "\\SNHU-LABS-UTIL2.snhu-labs.com\userprofiles$\karen.obando\Documents\GP_VDI\Final\Final.py", line 80, in <module>
        polyLine = arcpy.Polyline(PList)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.6\ArcPy\arcpy\arcobjects\mixins.py", line 231, in __init__
        *gp_fixargs(args, True))
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.6\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 510, in <lambda>
        return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
    RuntimeError: Object: CreateObject cannot create geometry from inputs

import arcpy
import os

arcpy.env.workspace = r'\\SNHU-LABS-UTIL2.snhu-labs.com\\userprofiles$\\karen.obando\\Documents\\GP_VDI\\Final\\Data'

path = r'\\SNHU-LABS-UTIL2.snhu-labs.com\userprofiles$\karen.obando\Documents\GP_VDI\Final\Data'
print path
outfile = "lines.shp"

print "START"
# OS walk to find appropriate files in folder
# establish path
# create Array
for folder, subs, files in os.walk(path):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith(".txt"):
            print filename
            
            filePath = (os.path.join(folder, filename))
            infile = open(filePath, "r")
            PList = arcpy.Array()

            print filePath

# Split coordinate lines by comma
            for item in infile:
                segment = item.split(", ")
                
# Split and identify spatial reference
                if item.startswith("Spatial"):
                    split = item.split(": ")

                    spatRef = arcpy.SpatialReference(int(split[1]))
                    print spatRef
                
# Create feature class
# Open cursor
                    try:
                        inFeature = arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(path, outfile, "polyline", "", "", "", spatRef)
                        arcpy.AddField_management(inFeature, "Name", "STRING", "", "", "")
                        arcpy.AddField_management(inFeature, "Date", "STRING", "", "", "")
                        cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(inFeature, ["Name", "Date", "SHAPE@"])
                    except:
                        inFeature = outfile
                        print "Feature class already exists"
                        cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(inFeature, ["Name", "Date", "SHAPE@"])

# Find separate coordinate by Name
                    if segment[0].startswith("Name"):
                        split = item.split(": ")

# Check array for coordinates, add to list with other data                       
                        if len(PList) > 0:
                            polyLine = arcpy.Polyline(PList, {26917})
                            cursor.insertRow((LName, date, polyLine))
                            print "Added " + LName
                            
                        LName = split[1]
                        PList = arcpy.Array()

# Split and store names  and dates
                    elif segment[0].startswith("Spatial"):
                        pass

                    elif segment[0].startswith("Work"):
                        split = item.split(": ")
                        date = split[1]
                    else:
                        try:
                            print segment[0]
                            point = arcpy.Point(segment[0], segment[1])
                            PList.add(point)
                        except:
                            pass

# Ensure last polyline is created 
                polyLine = arcpy.Polyline(PList, {26917})
                cursor.insertRow((LName, date, polyLine))
                print "Added  " + LName

# delete cursor, close file
                del cursor
                infile.close()

print "Done"
```

Comment: Please do not delete and repost question variants. Instead, Edit the original question to provide the requested clarity.  Placing a print statement *after* the location of the error is unlikely to help.  Instead you want to provide enough print statements to follow the flow of control in your application.

Comment: Also, the current question gives us no idea what you've attempted or changed to try and resolve your issue.

Comment: Add a sample of the text file (as text, not screenshot) to your question

Answer (score 1):

Your "cannot create geometry" error is caused by your passing in the spatial reference as a dictionary (using the curley bracket)

```
polyLine = arcpy.Polyline(PList, {26917})
```

when you see the {} in the help documentation, it means this is an optional argument.
Seeing as you already have the spatial reference you could just do:

```
polyLine = arcpy.Polyline(PList, spatRef)
```

Or is you are trying to use 26917 specifically. Code it like this:

```
polyLine = arcpy.Polyline(PList,arcpy.SpatialReference(26917))
```